# Multi-relay interlock circuit/control

Tags: relay, control

I have eight different kV motors that I need to run from the same source. I cannot change the topology to have different sources for each motor. Ideally something that simply turns the relays on one at a time for five minutes at a time would be fine. I need to ensure with a degree of certainty that:

1. Two or more motors cannot be run at the same time
2. Between switching motors there should be a small dead time.

I cannot use a cheap (/chinese) relay board controller but it needs to come from a reputable supplier. I have read alot about using two contactors to INTERLOCK a motor to go forward and reverse but cannot find a way to daisy chain them. However the word interlock is defined for two devices, so it might be that I am missing the correct terminology to find the component.

Does anyone know of any topologies, hierarchies or components that could resolve this for me?

Comment: What's a kV motor?

Comment: A motor that requires a 1.5kV supply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would use a proper industrial PLC (Programmable Logic Controller) from a reputable supplier, not a board-level device from any supplier of any pedigree.

Secondly, you can simply daisy-chain relay normally-closed contacts to create an additional hardware interlock.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8IOQy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using industrial power contactors with add-on contacts, you can prevent to start more than one motor at once, this is fairly simple relay logics.

[image]

There are also pneumatic timers, for those contactors. They are expensive, but I have never seen anything more robust than those timers.

[image]

You should describe more in detail, what you need. Perhaps you will need also motor protection circuit, perhaps a small PLC like Siemens LOGO if you need a software interlock and timer, perhaps some kind of start/stop switch,...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f24l9v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>